# How to append "user is typing to label", and removing after 5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets

I'm trying to build a chat program. I have read several guides (such as: http://www.tamas.io/further-additions-to-the-node-jssocket-io-chat-app/), 
however I still can't get it to work. 
When someone is typing, the "is typing" is not added to the other user's label.

I really hope someone can point out where I have gone wrong.

Thanks,

Here's my code.

client-side:

```
// Detect typing
      var typing = false;  
      var timeout = undefined;

      function timeoutFunction() {  
        typing = false;
        socket.emit("typing", false);
        socket.emit("notTyping", true)
      }

      $("#msg").keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which !== 13) {
          if (typing === false && $("#msg").is(":focus")) {
            notTyping = false;
            typing = true;
            socket.emit("typing", true);
          } else {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);
          }
        }
      });

      client.on("isTyping", function(msg) {
          $typingActivity.append('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
          timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);
      });
```

server-side:

```
client.on("typing", function(data) {  
    console.log("Typing...");
    client.broadcast.emit("isTyping", people[client.id] + " is typing...");
});
```

Comment: Check for errors in your browser's console.

Comment: I just visited the link you provided and as far as i can see they use socket.on instead of client.on. I cant see where you initiate client variable so in my opinion just rename client to socket and it should work

Comment: Yea, I noticed that. I've tried renaming them, however then the server does not "hear" the typing,

Comment: Could you provide some jsFiddle so i could help you out by editing it?

Comment: Sorry you were right. Changing it to socket works. The label "is typing" append to other user's screen, however multiple times. Should I add both clientside and serverside in same window in fiddle?

Comment: UPDATE! It does work now, but the label "is typing" is not removed after 5 seconds.

Comment: I dont see any code above that would remove the "is typing" label. I will add answer because i cant format the code in here. Wait a second

Comment: I deleted the answer cause it didnt help you and i dont have enough time in this week to go through all of that documentation that would be needed to help you. Sorry mate. I will get back to it next week. I hope somebody else will help you in the meantime. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: That ok! Thanks for your time!